# Proving matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove the following: 
$$[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{a})}{\partial \mathbf{a}}]^T \times \mathbf{e} = f(\mathbf{a})\otimes \mathbf{e}-\langle{f(\mathbf{a}),\mathbf{e}}\rangle f(\mathbf{a})$$ where $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are $\in \mathbb{R}^{10}$.
I've proven the following: $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{a}_i)}
{\partial a_j} = -f(\mathbf{a}_j)f(\mathbf{a}_i)$ for $i \neq j$. I've also proved that $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{a}_i)}
{\partial a_i}=f(\mathbf{a}_i)(1-f(\mathbf{a}_i))$ for $i=j$.

I also know that since $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{a})}{\partial \mathbf{a}}$ is a symmetric matrix, $f(\mathbf{a})\otimes \mathbf{e}$ is essentially element-wise multiplication of the main diagonal.

I understand that the angle brackets represent inner product which in this case becomes just a dot product. However, I'm not sure how to mathematically prove the above identity other than just explaining it in words.